# This site can't be reached docs/docker.github.io

Tags: docker

I ran

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 docs/docker.github.io
```

and the output shows

```
Docker docs are viewable at:
http://0.0.0.0:4000
```

however when I go to this address I get an error

```
 This site can’t be reached

 The web page at http://0.0.0.0:4000/ might be temporarily down or it may 
 have moved permanently to a new web address.
 ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is a listener address that indicates all network interfaces on a machine, you don't connect to this address because it doesn't exist. Instead, you need to connect your browser to the IP address or name of the docker host. If you're running this locally, without docker-machine, that would be http://127.0.0.1:4000. With docker-machine, you can get the IP of the VM from the `docker-machine ip` output.

Comment: Thank you. 
"a listener address that indicates all network interfaces on a machine,"   What is a listener address and what is a network interface ?

Comment: Is a "listener address" like a wild card asterix in dos ?

Comment: This question may clarify it more: https://serverfault.com/q/78048/351549

Comment: A TCP connection transfers data between two parties, a server that listens for connections, and a client that connects to the server. The network interface is every device, physical or virtual, with an IP address. Some physical examples include the connection for the network cable and the wifi adapter.

Answer (score 8):

What I found using Docker for Windows is that the references to localhost or 0.0.0.0 didn't work at all when I tried to access the application in the browser. It's using Docker Quickstart Terminal which runs a Linux image on Windows and it runs Docker inside that

This command provides the IP address of the Linux image

```
docker-machine ip
```

When I use that address on my Windows browser it works fine, for example:

http://192.168.99.100:4999/

Comment: I was able to do it this way and the localhost way

Comment: Docker Machine is now deprecated (https://docs.docker.com/machine/). It is suggested to use docker desktop instead. But if you only want to get the virtual machine ip, just do ipconfig and look for "Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)" or similar.